# Добрый день. Осваиваю Linux и возник ряд вопросов

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня Windows и поэтому я установил ubuntu server с помощью виртуальной машины. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Desktop мне совершенно не нужен, потому что я буду работать только в командной строке?
Так же, я подключил сервер, все делал по инструкции с ютуба. Командная строка работает, но пропустил важную часть видео про настройку ssh сервера. Не совсем понимаю что это, для чего нужно и необходимо ли мне, не могли бы вы пояснить ?
Еще при работе в виртуальной машине пропадает курсов мыши, когда я нахожусь в командной строке. Можно ли что-то с этим сделать?

Comment: А для чего вы Linux устанавливаете? Для домашнего использования? Или сервер собираетесь делать?

Comment: Во-первых, сами решайте, нужен ли вам desktop. Во-вторых, ssh — это протокол для подключения к компьютеру по сети, и опять же сами решайте, нужно ли вам оно. В-третьих, если вы хотите курсор мыши в командной строке, то установите gpm

Comment: А в-четвёртых, в вопросе должен быть один вопрос, так что этот вопрос будет закрыт как слишком общий

Comment: Для освоения лучше поставьте desctop. Возможно, через некоторое время linux вам понравится (это если внутри вы правильный программер) и винда станет больше уже не нужна

Comment: Desktop не нужен, а вот ssh сервер - очень даже. Собственно это то, что позволит вам получить доступ к командной строке, а то сейчас вы по ходу используете окошко, которое показывает виртуальная машина. Вместо этого следует подключаться к серверу по ssh используя putty или аналогичный клиент ssh.

Comment: @user7860670 в PowerShell достаточно `ssh user@ip` зачем путти и тд

Comment: @Jour Чтобы хранить команды и чтобы управлять консолью. Исполняемый файл ssh удобно использовать только в скрипте.

Comment: @user7860670 я о том, что из стандартной консоли винды можно подключится к удаленному серверу) Исполняемый файл вы похоже имеете ввиду не ssh а .sh

Comment: @Jour Да-да, из обычной консоли можно подключиться к серверу, но это неудобно. Под исполняемым файлом я имею ввиду ssh.exe, который используется в этом случае.